# When I float element, I can't understand the placement of the elements

Tags: css

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;  
  
}

.image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.image2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6o4ynucb/

When I thought, image2 seems to have to come under image1, but it doesn't take up space. What is the problem?

Comment: Hello, this is happening because of the `.image` height. change the .image height similar to .image1 and see your problem will be resolved

Comment: It goes under image because of display:inline-block. Replace display:inline-block with float:right and image2 will go under imgae1. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jtaq8vnw/

Comment: @MDMNauman and can you explain *why*?

Comment: @Will Thanks. I know how to solve it. but I wonder why display:inline-block is causing the problem in detail.

Comment: @TemaniAfif because .image doesn't have the float property so it's in the normal flow of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules) to understand this behavior. If you check the rule you can read the following:

> 6. The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top **of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document**.

Then for the line box you can read:

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them may be aligned. **The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box.** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box)</sup>

In your case, the `inline-block` is creating a line box where its height is logically defined by that inline-block <sup>1</sup>. The first float can sit inside that line box on the left (there is enough room) but not the second float. So the rule (6) will apply and it will start under that line box.

Here is a small animation of the float element width to better see:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;  
  
}

.image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.image2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

> A floated box is shifted **to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float**. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned **with the top of the current line box**.
>
> If there is **not enough horizontal room for the float**, it is shifted **downward** until either it fits or there are no more floats present.

More details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats

Another intresting result if you make the height of inline-block smaller:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;  
  
}

.image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.image2 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

1. when both width are less than 50%, both can fit inside the line box before the inline-block
2. when both width exceed 50% the next float is moved downward and start at the top of the line box defined by the inline-block and touch the right edge of the first float
3. when each width is bigger than 50%, both float move downward

---

<sup>1</sup> Note the small space between the inline-block and the float when they move downward. This is due to the baseline alignment which is an important fact in defining the line box.

You can change the alignment to remove it:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;  
  
}

.image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.image2 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @newbieeyo yes take your time, you need to read slowly and try at the same time to understand correctly because it not easy to understand such things (you may need to read it many times)

Answer (score -1):

You shoud try like that :

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='col1'>
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image2"></div>
</div>
<div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

And the css :

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;  

}

.col1 {
  float: left;
   width: 50%;
}

.image1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.image2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Why should he do that? [answer]